# Search button doesn't stay beside input (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edalzell/gujww7d7/1/

HTML is here:

```
    <header class= "blog-masthead">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch" name="query" value="{{ get:query|sanitize }}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

My page works when the browswer is > 768 px but less than that and the search button drops below the input field. I want it to stay beside.

I have looked here: http://www.mentful.com/2014/06/22/fixed-search-navbar-with-bootstrap-3-0/

Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use "input-group" option to acheive this. Below code will work for you.

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch" name="query" >
     <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
</div>
```

One More Option to Achieve this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/4rn48ct4/

Comment: Thanks, I used your first example and it works great!!